# C# web browser randomly freezes when trying to login to check e-mail?

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a C# Web Browser, I am trying to access: my.screenname.aol.com for mail, but it won't even load, I don't have much code...as you can see:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EmailViewer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            webBrowser1.Navigate("my.screenname.aol.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `"http://my.screenname.aol.com"` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth a shot to try WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed Property to true.